# Why doesn't /bin/login appear in ps output when someone is logging in

Tags: bash, login, strace

I wanted to monitor what happens when a test user logs in to my CentOS 6.4 system, so I tried this to poll ps for `/bin/login` and `strace` the pid when it appears:

```
until [[ $(ps -ef|grep -q [l]ogin)$? -eq 0 ]]; do 
    true; 
done && strace pidof /bin/login
```

I SSH'd in from another system and checked on the system, but no `strace` ever happened.  Why doesn't `login` show up in `ps`?  the user's shell is bash and it connects without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your `sshd_config` file, you don't have `UseLogin yes`. The default is `no`. From the manual page:

```
UseLogin
        Specifies whether login(1) is used for interactive login ses‐
        sions.  The default is “no”.  Note that login(1) is never used
        for remote command execution.  Note also, that if this is
        enabled, X11Forwarding will be disabled because login(1) does not
        know how to handle xauth(1) cookies.  If UsePrivilegeSeparation
        is specified, it will be disabled after authentication.
```